# Change background css to blur when button is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, css

how add an attribute `filter: blur(2px);` to `body` when a `button` is clicked? and when the close button is clicked, remove that attribute from `body`? Cheers

Comment: Take a look at `.css()` http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: to remove the attribute just do <code>$('body').css('filter', '');</code>

Answer (score 1):

I think u want this:

On button click:

```
$("#btnid").click(function(){
  $('body').css("filter","blur(2px)");
});
```

To remove:

```
   $("#closebtnid").click(function(){
      $('body').css("filter","");
    });
```

[**css() method**](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: I tried, doesn't work :/ do i have to add blur(0) in the css of body?

Comment: do i need to add -webkit-?

Comment: it depends on browser.if required just add  $('body').css("-webkit-filter","blur(2px)");

Comment: okay webkit seems to be the trick, however the whole document goes blur, because when the button is clicked, a div will be visible. I don't want the div to be blurred as well, how can i do that? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In **CSS** create 2 classes - one with the blur and one without.

In **Javascript** create 2 functions - 1 *onclick* for the blur-button and 1 *onclick* for the close button. These functions should change the class of *body*.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('body').addClass('blur');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is better to add or remove a class instead of using .css(). First of all it splits your styling from the business logic (easier maintenance). Also `addClass()` is faster then the `css()` method.

css

```
   .blurfilter{
       /*your blur filter styles here*/
    }
```

jquery

```
$('.blurbutton').on('click', function(){
   $('body').addClass('blurfilter');
});

$('.unblurbutton').on('click', function(){
   $('body').removeClass('blurfilter');
});

//you also could toggle the class with one button
$('.togglebutton').on('click', function(){
   $('body').toggleClass('blurfilter');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `css()` to add any css property to the selected item

```
$('#button').click(function(){
   $('body').css("filter", "blur(2px)");
});
```

To remove the css property

```
$('#button').click(function(){
   $('body').css("filter", "");
});
```

***Note :*** `#button` is id of button.

***Documentation :*** http://api.jquery.com/css/